# MySQL Query: Using group by and getting unreal results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query and I'm stuck.
Previously I had two tables, one with job details and one with employee details. Now I took one column from the employee table and added it to the job table, resulting in unreal results when trying to write a query using `group by`.

My Query:

```
 SELECT SAL, COUNT(COMM), COUNT(EMPNO) FROM EMPLOYEE, JOB GROUP BY JOBCODE;
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| SAL     | COUNT(COMM) | COUNT(EMPNO) |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| 3000.00 |           4 |           12 |
| 3000.00 |           4 |            4 |
| 3000.00 |           0 |            4 |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

While it should have been:

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| SAL     | COUNT(COMM) | COUNT(EMPNO) |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| 3000.00 |           1 |            3 |
| 1800.00 |           1 |            1 |
| 2000.00 |           0 |            1 |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

Essentially I am getting 4 times the number of people with `COMM` and 4 times the number of `EMPLOYEE` for each `JOB`. Also, I am getting only one of the three `SAL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't just `GROUP BY`, it is `JOIN` -- or the lack thereof.

Very simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT JOBCODE, AVG(SAL), COUNT(COMM), COUNT(EMPNO)
FROM EMPLOYEE e JOIN
     JOB j
     ON e.?? = j.??
GROUP BY JOBCODE;
```

Your question doesn't provide enough information to specify the proper `JOIN` conditions between the tables.

When you do `GROUP BY` something, all other columns should have aggregation functions.

Comment: Will accept the answer in 5', thank you very much, I am really new in MySQL so I didn't know anything about join. Can you explain to me what the code in `JOIN` does? The question marks would be `JOBCODE` and `JOBNO` and it works perfectly.